# TicTacToe Tie Error

Tags: python

So this is my Tic.Tac.Toe game, and it works okay. But I have a function to check wether the board is full or not, and that doesn't work. I'm able to get it to go to player 1, then player 2, but after it stops. Can someone please help?

```
# Tic Tac Toe Game
import time
import sys
who = 'p1'
finished = 'no'
board = [0,1,2,
         3,4,5,
         6,7,8]

def show():
    print (board[0], '|', board [1], '|', board[2])
    print ('---------')
    print (board[3], '|', board [4], '|', board[5])
    print ('---------')
    print (board[6], '|', board [7], '|', board[8])

def checkWin():
    if board[0] == 'x' and board[3] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[3] == 'y' and board[6] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[1] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[1] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[7] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'y' and board[5] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[1] == 'y' and board[2] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[1] == 'x' and board[2] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[3] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[3] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[5] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[6] == 'y' and board[7] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[6] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[0] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'y' and board[4] == 'y' and board[6] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    elif board[2] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    else:
        return False

def boardFull():
    if board[0] == 'x' or board[0] == 'y' and board[1] == 'x' or board[1] == 'y' and board[2] == 'x' or board[2] == 'y' and board[3] == 'x' or board[3] == 'y' and board[4] == 'x' or board[4] == 'y' and board[5] == 'x' or board[5] == 'y' and board[6] == 'x' or board[6] == 'y' and board[6] == 'x' or board[6] == 'y' and board[7] == 'x' or board[7] == 'y' and board[8] == 'x' or board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    else:
        finished = 'no'
        return False


print ('Welcome to a two-player Tic.Tac.Toe Game!')
time.sleep(2)
print ("Just pick a spot to put your mark!")
time.sleep(1.5)
print ('Now, start!')
time.sleep(0.2)
print (show())

while checkWin() == False and boardFull() == False:
    while who == 'p1':
        try:
            p1 = int(input('Player 1, select a spot: '))

            if board[p1] != 'x' and board[p1] != 'o':
                board[p1] = 'x'
                who = 'p2'
                break

            else:
                print ('This spot is taken.')
                pass

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print ('That is not available. Please try again.')

    print (show())
    while who == 'p2':
        try:
            p2 = int(input('Player 2, select a spot: '))

            if board[p2] != 'x' and board[p2] != 'o':
                board[p2] = 'o'
                who = 'p1'
                break

            else:
                print ('This spot is taken.')
                pass

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print ('That is not available. Please try again.')

    print (show())
while checkWin() == True:
    if boardFull() == False:

        # x
        if board[0] == 'x' and board[3] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[1] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[2] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[0] == 'x' and board[1] == 'x' and board[2] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[3] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[5] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[6] == 'x' and board[7] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[0] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[8] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
        elif board[2] == 'x' and board[4] == 'x' and board[6] == 'x':
            print ('Player 1 won!')
            sys.exit()
    # y
        else:
            print ('Player 2 won!')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print ("It's a tie.")
```

Comment: To start with, the function `boardFull` begins with `if board[0] == 'x' or ... : return True`, which is wrong; it will evaluate to `True` even if only square 0 is `x`.

Comment: you should fill board with one value - ie. `0` and then you have to check `board[0] != '0'` instead of `board[0] == 'x' or board[0] == 'y'`

Comment: you could create `checkWin` with argument - and run `checkWin('x')` and `checkWin('y')` - this way code inside `checkWin` will be simpler.

Comment: loops `while who == 'p1':` and `while who == 'p2':` are very similar - you could create one function and execute with different arguments - code will be simpler and shorter.

Comment: @Something, I made a gist with some improvements to your code in order to help you out and illustrate a bit more Pythonic and programmer friendly way to write this. Feel free to leave comments on the gist if you have questions. https://gist.github.com/mreinhardt/cfdeeb3121ef1e6c00820d8a15677812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many problems. One is that you set `x` or `o` on board but you check `x` or `y`. Next is that `boardFull()` return `True` after two moves. But you can count correct moves instead of checking all cells. After 9 correct moves board will be full.

---

Your code could be shorter

`show()` prints board so you can call it without `print()` - `print(show())`

`checkWin()` could return `False` or winner `x` or `o` which is treated as `True` and at the end you don't have to check again who is winner.

In `while` loop you don't check if board is full between move of player 1 and 2 so game hangs because full board is full after move of player 1 and player 2 can't make move.

---

`checkWin()` checks only current player if it is a winner after its last move.
I count correct moves to check if board is full - after 9 moves board should be full.

```
# Tic Tac Toe Game

import time

# --- fucntions ---

def show(board):
    print('''-----------
 {} | {} | {}
-----------
 {} | {} | {}
-----------
 {} | {} | {}
-----------'''.format(*board))


def check_winner(board, q):

    if board[0] == q and board[3] == q and board[6] == q:
        return True
    elif board[1] == q and board[4] == q and board[7] == q:
        return True
    elif board[2] == q and board[5] == q and board[8] == q:
        return True

    elif board[0] == q and board[1] == q and board[2] == q:
        return True
    elif board[3] == q and board[4] == q and board[5] == q:
        return True
    elif board[6] == q and board[7] == q and board[8] == q:
        return True

    elif board[0] == q and board[4] == q and board[8] == q:
        return True
    elif board[2] == q and board[4] == q and board[6] == q:
        return True

    return False

# --- start ---

board = list(range(9))

player = 'x'
number = '1'

moves = 0

print('Welcome to a two-player Tic.Tac.Toe Game!')
time.sleep(2)

print("Just pick a spot to put your mark!")
time.sleep(1.5)

print('Now, start!')
time.sleep(0.2)

show(board)

while True:

    while True:
        try:
            idx = int(input('Player {}, select a spot: '.format(number)))

            if board[idx] not in ('x', 'o'):
                board[idx] = player
                moves += 1
                break
            else:
                print('This spot is taken.')

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print('That is not available. Please try again.')

    show(board)

    winner = check_winner(board, player)

    if winner or moves == 9:
        break

    # change player after checking who win 
    if player == 'x':
        player = 'o'
        number = '2' 
    else:
        player = 'x'
        number = '1'

if winner:
    print('Player {} won!'.format(number))
else:
    print("It's a tie.")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that the problem lies in the implementation of `boardFull` as 101 says. I don't have precedence rules memorised (which is why it's often a good idea to use parentheses in complex expressions, even where they're not technically required) but I believe "or" has lower precedence than "and", meaning `boardFull` will return `True` if `board[0]` has been set, regardless of the rest of the board's state.

I'd start off by modifying `boardFull` to accept `board` as a parameter, rather than have it check the state of a global variable. This makes the function easier to reason about, easier to test, and improves reusability. I also write a simple test suite for testing its behaviour:

```
import unittest

def create_board():
    return list(range(0, 9))

def board_full(board):
    if board[0] == 'x' or board[0] == 'y' and board[1] == 'x' or board[1] == 'y' and board[2] == 'x' or board[2] == 'y' and board[3] == 'x' or board[3] == 'y' and board[4] == 'x' or board[4] == 'y' and board[5] == 'x' or board[5] == 'y' and board[6] == 'x' or board[6] == 'y' and board[6] == 'x' or board[6] == 'y' and board[7] == 'x' or board[7] == 'y' and board[8] == 'x' or board[8] == 'y':
        finished = 'yes'
        return True
    else:
        finished = 'no'
        return False

class TestBoardFull(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.board = create_board()

    def test_default_board_is_not_full(self):
        default_board = self.board
        self.assertFalse(board_full(default_board))

    def test_board_after_two_moves_is_not_full(self):
        board = self.board
        board[0] = 'x'
        board[1] = 'y'
        self.assertFalse(board_full(board))

    def test_board_is_full_after_all_tiles_marked(self):
        board = self.board
        board[0] = 'x'
        board[1] = 'y'
        board[2] = 'x'
        board[3] = 'y'
        board[4] = 'x'
        board[5] = 'y'
        board[6] = 'x'
        board[7] = 'y'
        board[8] = 'x'
        self.assertTrue(board_full(board))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Currently, `board_full(board)` uses your original implementation, which we can show is incorrect:

```
F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_board_after_two_moves_is_not_full (__main__.TestBoardFull)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<<my_name>>/.PyCharmCE2016.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 26, in test_board_after_two_moves_is_not_full
    self.assertFalse(board_full(board))
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I then attempt to correct the implementation:

```
def board_full(board):
    return all(tile == 'x' or tile == 'y' for tile in board)
```

And test that this works, at least according to the tests I've currently defined:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```